# Route planning with detours for "nearby" Points of Interest

Tags: web-mapping, routing, web-service, point-of-interest

I want to know if Google maps, Open Streetmap, or some alternative, lets me plan a route by foot (or bicycle, maybe also car, or even public transportation, but by foot is my initial project) from point A to point B  …

BUT… it should be able to offer a detour  if certain points of interest are “nearby”, where I get to define “nearby”, whether in terms of distance or time added, and I can choose from the API's POIs, or define my own list.

Comment: Have a look at a similar thing I did: https://graphhopper.com/blog/2015/05/05/solving-the-electric-vehicle-charging-problematic-fast-with-graphhopper/

Comment: That looks like just what I want, and it is a bonus that you put the source code on GitHub. From what you write, I may have to pay if I make heavy use of the GraphHopper Matrix API, but that its acceptable (aha! You are co-founder? Well, that’s good, know I know who to ask questions to). Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments: there is a simple solution via fetching the POIs calculating the detours and picking the best route in the end like I did with similar requirements [here](https://graphhopper.com/blog/2015/05/05/solving-the-electric-vehicle-charging-problematic-fast-with-graphhopper/).

Another option would be to attach the POI information directly in the graph, and do the graph search (Dijkstra or A*) until you find a set of suitable ones, then calculate the routes from them to the destination. This is more complex but avoids knowing the specific POIs up-front.

Comment: It is highly likely that I will have to add my own POI list